# Change orientation of one of Y axis of a HConcat

Tags: altair

For the below HConcat charts, I want to change the orientation of y2 to be on the right hand side. Could you please help.

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

x = ['a', 'b']
y1 = [10, 20]
y2 = [12, 15]

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'y1':y1, 'y2':y2})

Chart1 = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
        alt.X('x'),
        alt.Y('y1')
)
Chart2 = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
        alt.X('x'),
        alt.Y('y2')
)

Chart1|Chart2
```

Result
[Both Y axes on left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqeQd.png)

Expected:
[y1 on left and y2 on right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dttnS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can orient the axis of the second plot to the right with:

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

x = ['a', 'b']
y1 = [10, 20]
y2 = [12, 15]

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'y1':y1, 'y2':y2})

Chart1 = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
        alt.X('x'),
        alt.Y('y1')
)
Chart2 = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
        alt.X('x'),
        alt.Y('y2', axis=alt.Axis(orient="right")),
)

Chart1|Chart2
```